# Regex expression to capture hyphenated word between lines, and non hyphenated words

Tags: java, regex, match, capture

I am trying to write a regular expression, in java, that matches words and hyphenated words. So far I have:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?:-\\w+)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s)[\\w]+-$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This is my test case:

```
    Programs
    Dsfasdf. Programs Programs Dsfasdf. Dsfasdf. as is wow woah! woah. woah? okay. 
    he said, "hi." aasdfa. wsdfalsdjf. go-to go-
to
asdfasdf.. , : ; " ' ( ) ? ! - / \ @ # $ % & ^ ~ `  * [ ] { } + _ 123
```

Any help would be awesome

My expected result would be to match all the words ie.

```
Programs Dsfasdf Programs Programs Dsfasdf Dsfasdf
as is wow woah woah woah okay he said hi aasdfa
wsdfalsdjf go-to go-to asdfasdf
```

the part I'm struggling with is matching the words that are split up between lines as one word.

ie.

```
go-
to
```

Comment: So you want to match words, both with and without hyphens? But not punctuation or digits? Also your expected/desired result from your test case would be useful.

Comment: It isn't really clear to me what you mean with "hyphenated word *between lines*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\p{L}+(?:-\n?\p{L}+)*
\   /^\ /^\ /\   /^^^
 \ / | | | |  \ / |||
  |  | | | |   |  ||`- Previous can repeat 0 or more times (group of literal '-', optional new-line and one or more of any letter (upper/lower case))
  |  | | | |   |  |`-- End first non-capture group
  |  | | | |   |  `--- Match one or more of previous (any letter, upper/lower case)
  |  | | | |   `------ Match any letter (upper/lower case)
  |  | | | `---------- Match a single new-line (optional because of `?`)
  |  | | `------------ Literal '-'
  |  | `-------------- Start first non-capture group
  |  `---------------- Match one or more of previous (any letter between A-Z (upper/lower case))
  `------------------- Match any letter (upper/lower case)
```

[Is this OK?](http://rubular.com/r/Ryktjf42w7)

Comment: Was that generated automatically? If so, where is this from?

Comment: What about for words split up between lines? In my test case the go-to is split up between 2 lines.  I did have that (basically) as p1 in my question minus the ? at the end.

Comment: Did not realize it should be valid. Updated regex to reflect requested changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with regex:

```
\p{L}+(?:\-\p{L}+)*
```

Such regex should match also words *"fiancé"*, *"À-la-carte"* and other words containing some special category "letter" characters. `\p{L}` matches a single code point in the category "letter".